# How to test a RASA model?

Tags: python, nlp, chatbot, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I'm trying to write my own chatbot with the RASA framework.
Right now I'm just playing around with it and I have the following piece of code for training purposes.

```
from rasa.nlu.training_data import load_data
from rasa.nlu.config import RasaNLUModelConfig
from rasa.nlu.model import Trainer
from rasa.nlu import config
training_data = load_data("./data/nlu.md")
trainer = Trainer(config.load("config.yml"))
interpreter = trainer.train(training_data)
model_directory = trainer.persist("./models/nlu",fixed_model_name="current")
```

Now, I read that if I wanted to test it I should do something like this.

```
from rasa.nlu.evaluate import run_evaluation
run_evaluation("nlu.md", model_directory)
```

But this code is not available anymore in rasa.nlu.evaluate nor in rasa.nlu.test! 
What's the way, then, of testing a RASA model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module was renamed.
Please import

```
from rasa.nlu.test import run_evaluation
```

Alternatively you now also do

```
from rasa.nlu import test
test_result = test(path_to_test_data, unpacked_model)

intent_evaluation_report = test_result["intent_evaluation"]["report"]
print(intent_evaluation_report)
```

Comment: From the iPython console I can only get a JSON of predictions (+ metrics) printed, while I see from this link  (https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-conversational-chatbot-for-slack-using-rasa-and-python-part-1-bca5cc75d32f) that previously it made, as the output, a confusion matrix. Is that still possible?

Comment: Sure. The easiest way is probably to just run `rasa test` in your commandline (using Rasa 1.0) . Which version are you currently using? That should actually work with the command from above.

Comment: I'm using V1.0. What if I would like to see the confusion matrix (via a graphic) with Python? Is there no way to do so?